# history.back() not working for li element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

> I used history.back() or history.back(-1) to navigate to previous screen by clicking on a li element in my mvc application. But it is not working. I found a [Similar problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25673477/window-history-back-not-working) but I cant use this solution as I cant give li type='button' what to do ?[image: <code>Image here</code>]`function goBackScreen() {
>       window.history.back(); return false;
>   }`

Comment: on buttons the return false is used to stop a postback, so to go back you would need a postback (just a thought), is you want to go back on ajaxy elements then you need to reload the partial or data i guess.

Comment: i just want to go on the page where i came from

Answer (score 0):

if `back` id is added to `li`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#back').click(function(){
        if(document.referrer.indexOf(window.location.hostname) != -1){
            parent.history.back();
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with "widow.history.back()", It works fine even if trigger is not a button.

The anchor tag you have placed inside`<li>` is preventing that action to bubble to`<li>`.

- Bind onClick to anchor tag  :`<li ><a href="javaScript:void(0)" onClick="goback()">Go Back</a></li>`
- Remove anchor tag from the "LI" :`<li onClick="goback()" >Go Back</li>`   Note : This will affect your UI
  Last option is to find targeted element through "event.currentTarget" and bind your function to it. also have to add "event.preventDefault()" on anchor tag.