# Back Button with Javascript in Jira Velocity

Tags: javascript, html, jira, back

I am currently developing a velocity template for our Jira instance. Thereby, I inserted a button to go one page back. Unfortunately with the JavaScript I inserted nothing happens. Is the code wrong? Do I have to consider something special?

```
<!-- Back Button -->
   <span style="align:right">
     <button id="description-back-button", onclick="goBack()", class="aui-button">Back to iCockpit </button>
        <script>
        function goBack() {
            window.history.back();
        }
        </script>
   </span>
  </div>
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: What doesn't work ? Because it works fine with me on IE, Chrome and Mozilla

Comment: When I click the button, nothing happens....it just reloads the current page.

Comment: Try adding type="button" .

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15750407/inconsistency-with-window-history-back?rq=1

Comment: Replace your button with `<button id="description-back-button" onclick="window.history.back();" class="aui-button">Back to iCockpit </button>`

Comment: eventually this might be because I was asked on the page before if I wanted to leave that page. I clicked yes and reached this page with the back button. Maybe this could be the reason why? However, I am still in the same tab.

Comment: thanks for this code adjustment. Inserted and tested it. Didn't work. It just reloads the page. maybe this might be due to that notification I received when accessing the page with the back button?

Comment: Let's break it, click many times very fast on this button, does something seem to happen ? If yes it's because you're redirecting right after you clicked the button

Comment: Manualy go back using the left arrow on the top left corner, is it doing something different from your button ?

Comment: still nothing happening:/ it gets into an endless reloading process

Comment: yes, when I do it manually it works fine

Comment: Because when you try to go historic back you're reaching a page that redirect you automaticaly

Comment: I'm sorry but it works fine with me..

Comment: how could I suppress the notification "do you want to leave this site"? maybe if I can go from page A to page B without this question the historic back would work, do you think this could be the problem?

Comment: try `<input type="button" value="Back to iCockpit" class="aui-button" onclick="window.history.back();" id="description-back-button">`. Is it better ?

Comment: was this alert created by you ?

Comment: here we go ;) thanks a lot. is this probably a jira issue? or did I do something wrong? However, thanks a lot for your quick help

Comment: I'm sorry but it works fine with me on every browser. I think that the page you're trying to redirect to automaticaly kicks you to another page

Comment: The alert was not created by me. That's the next issue I have to suppress this alert...

Comment: It happens sometimes that the server prefers <input type="button" rather than <button>

Comment: but the back button works no completely fine:)

Comment: ah ok, I see. Thanks for your hint:)

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead of `<button></button>`. It will correct your problem

```
<input type="button" value="Back to iCockpit" class="aui-button" onclick="window.history.back();" id="description-back-button">
```